# Ubuntu bluetooth audio via cron only works when logged in

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, cron

I am running Ubuntu server (headless) and have a bluetooth speaker connected to it. The objective is to play mp3 via cron.

Audio plays fine with cron using play command while I login or I keep a ssh connection alive to the server. As soon as I disconnect, any scheduled play commands via cron, do not play. Instead upon reconnection, they all start concurrently as if they were queued up.

My temp hack is to execute a forever sleep loop over ssh from another host via nohup. Looking for a permanent solution.

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Server/headless/without x) bluetoothctl ver 5.64.
Using play (from sox, play, rec) to play the audio (but open to other headless options)

Comment: In some distros, audio services are started when someone logs in and stopped when they log out.